# Can ii move to V43 over static bass just like IV can move V42?

Tags: theory, harmony, chord-progressions, voice-leading

In my harmony book (by Aldwell and Schachter) the progression from IV to V42 is a common one and gets its own section. But the book makes no mention of using scale degree ^2 in the bass. Is moving to V43 from ii less common, not worthy of mention or perhaps a bad chord progression?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, ii can absolutely go to V43! The main trick will not be moving between those two chords, but rather moving from I to ii (both in root position) without any parallels.

Similarly, I agree with Albrecht: I think IV–V42 is a bit more common. Note, however, that you can replace that IV with ii6 and move just as smoothly to V42.

Quite frankly, any use of tonic–predominant (IV or ii)–dominant works in this style. As long as tendency tones resolve correctly and you don't have any "illegal" six-four chords (more on those later in your book), any instance of smooth voice leading will work.

Answer (score 1):

This will be surely possible. Buit if a think just of 2 famous pieces where this could be tried  out
a) Largo (Handel): I'd prefer II vii6 or
b) Bist du bei mir (Bach):  ii-ii2-V56 is better.

So I think ii-V34 is less common than IV-V2.

Comment: what is II2? and What is V56? I know V65 only :)

Comment: ii2 is ii246 ( 3rd inversion of ii7), V56 is 1st inversion of V7). Obviouslly the English terminology is inverting the German one.

Comment: Thank you. The labellings are very confusing for me... it seems that every country has its own preferences